# Unable to import Spring bean definition file using relative path

Tags: java, spring, unit-testing

I am new to Spring and inherited a Spring project that had all the XML configuration in ProjectName/WebContent/WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml.  I'm trying to break the configuration into different components so it is easier to substitute things like DataSources and Hibernate configuation when testing.

Here is my file structure:

```
ProjectName
  ->WebContent
      ->WEB-INF
          ->applicationContext.xml
          ->spring-datasource.xml
          ->spring-hibernate-properties.xml
          ->spring-persistence.xml
  ->test
      ->us.mn.k12... (Java pkgs with JUnit tests)
      ->spring-hsqldb-datasource.xml
      ->spring-test-bean-locations.xml
      ->spring-test-hibernate-properties.xml
  ->src
      ->us.mn.k12... (Java pkgs with production code)
```

In WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml, I import the following:

```
<import resource="spring-datasource.xml"/> <!-- Production datasource -->
<import resource="spring-hibernate-properties.xml"/> <!-- Production hibernate properties -->
<import resource="spring-persistence.xml"/> <!--  DAO's, hibernate .hbm.xml mapping files -->
```

The application works with the above configuration.

My JUnit tests run using DbUnit and an HSQLDB in-memory database.  So my JUnit test references spring-test-bean-locations.xml, which has the following:

```
<import resource="spring-hsqldb-datasource.xml"/> <!-- HSQLDB datasource for test -->
<import resource="../WebContent/WEB-INF/spring-persistence.xml"/>  <!--  Production DAO's, hibernate .hbm.xml mapping files -->
<import resource="spring-test-hibernate-properties.xml"/> <!-- Hibernate properties for test -->
```

In this way, I can specify test datasource and hibernate properties, but reuse the production mapping file for the DAO's, etc. However, I get an error running my JUnit test. Here is the relevant part of the exception:

```
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.parsing.BeanDefinitionParsingException: Configuration problem: Failed to import bean definitions from relative location [../WebContent/WEB-INF/spring-persistence.xml]
Offending resource: class path resource [spring-test-bean-locations.xml]; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: IOException parsing XML document from class path resource [../WebContent/WEB-INF/spring-persistence.xml]; nested exception is java.io.FileNotFoundException: class path resource [../WebContent/WEB-INF/spring-persistence.xml] cannot be opened because it does not exist
```

Now if I move spring-persistence.xml into /test so that I don't have to use the relative path, and reference it with `<import resource="spring-persistence.xml"/>`, then the tests run fine. So I think the contents of my XML files are OK, but I'm not properly importing with a relative path.

Is there anything obvious I'm doing wrong with my import of the relative path? And maybe the bigger question is does this look like a reasonable strategy for breaking applicationContext.xml into components to make it easier for testing?

Thanks!

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The problem is: anything inside WEB-INF is not available to the ClassLoader in a regular project setup (and spring uses the ClassLoader by default to access resources). There are some hacks to work around this (like referencing the contexts using the file: prefix), but those are mostly ugly.

A better practice I'd suggest is to move the context files out of WEB-INF and into a dedicated resource directory (src/main/resources if you have a maven setup). That way they will be available to both the webapp ClassLoader and local unit test ClassLoaders.

Read the [resources chapter](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/resources.html) to further understand the mechanisms involved.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation Sean. We are using Ant and only have src, test, and WebContent/WEB-INF as the 3 nodes at the root of our project. Would putting the production Spring xml files in the src directory, and the test Spring xml in test directory be a typical setup? Or are other locations commonly used in a non-Maven setup. Thanks!

Comment: @buck64 yes, that would do. In maven there is a convention to keep classes seperate from resources, but to the classloader it's all the same.

Comment: if its the case so how can it be possible that my jars (with beans) are placed in /applications/Foo.ear/FooWebApp.war/WEB-INF/lib and everything works !?

Comment: @voipp if what is the case?

Answer (score 12):

Use

```
 <import resource="file:**/WebContent/WEB-INF/spring-persistence.xml" />
```

It works in spring 3.2.1.RELEASE.  Old versions I am not sure.